# A loop containing only even numbers

Tags: ruby, loops

I am doing a task to generate an array of fake email addresses in a given format.

I have managed to write a code that works for it. Here's what my code looks like:

```
emails = []
(1..50).each do |i|
  puts "jean.dupont.%02d@email.fr" %[i]
  emails.push(i)
end
```

This generates emails that look like this:

```
jean.dupont.01@email.fr
jean.dupont.02@email.fr
jean.dupont.03@email.fr
...
jean.dupont.50@email.fr
```

I am doing another task to generate the same thing, but only containing even numbers.

How can I add simple code to what I have, so it only gives even numbers?

Comment: Also [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) will return an `Array` based on the return value of the block so you could avoid `emails = []` and `emails.push(i)`

Comment: Do you want to generate 25 or 50 emails with the even numbers? Please answer by editing your question. Though not central to your question, the Ruby way of what you have is `arr = (1..50).map { |i|
"jean.dupont.%02d@email.fr" %[i] }` and then doing any desired `put`sing after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can change the range, then `step` would be your friend:

```
emails = []
(2..50).step(2) do |i|
  puts "jean.dupont.%02d@email.fr" %[i]
  emails.push(i)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The old school way (instructive for students):

```
emails = []
(1..50).each do |i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    puts "jean.dupont.%02d@email.fr" %[i]
    emails.push(i)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use [`Integer#even?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) for your conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your range to only even numbers by using the `.select` method, changing `(1..50).each` into `(1..50).select(&:even?).each`.

If you can change the range, then jerhinesmith's answer is nice too.